# Make sure that target inherit some interface for custom attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, custom-attributes

I need to create some custom attributes, to be used for my reflection functions.

Here is the usecase, as I see it:

- the user creates some class and marks it with my special attribute (**[ImportantAttribute]** for example)
- then the user does something with functions from my library.  Those functions find classes with **[ImportantAttribute]** and do something with them

The main problem is that functions in my library expects, that classes wich was marked with **[ImportantAttribute]** inherit my interface (**IMyInterface** for example)

Is there any way to let user know if he mark his class with **[ImportantAttribute]** and forget to inherit **IMyInterface** during compilation, not in run time. Some way to specify that this attribute is only for classes that inherit **IMyInterface**.

Same with attributes for properties and fields.

Comment: Why can't the user create his class with explicit inheritance from IMyInterface?  I.e., what does 'ImportantAttribute' bring to the party?

Comment: @Garry Vass this attribute says to my function, that it must aggregate marked class. User can create some class that inherit IMyInterface, and he don't whant my function to aggregate it. But all classes that marked with ImportantAttribute must implement IMyInterface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the strategy you mention in a couple of the frameworks I've built with good success. One such example is for providing metadata to a plug-in infrastructure:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple=false, Inherited=false)]
public class PluginAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

public interface IPlug
{
    void Run(IWork work);
}

[Plugin(DisplayName="Sample Plugin", Description="Some Sample Plugin")]
public class SamplePlug : IPlug
{
    public void Run(IWork work) { ... }
}
```

Doing so allows me to figure out information about plug-ins without having to instantiate them and read metadata properties.

In my experience in doing so, the only way I've found to enforce that both requirements are met is to perform runtime checks and make sure it is **bold** and <blink>blinking</blink> in the documentation. It is far from optimal but it is the best that can be done (that I've found). Then again I'm sure there is a better way to go about handling this but so far this has been pretty solid for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to let user know if he mark his class with
>   [ImportantAttribute] and forget to inherit IMyInterface during
>   compilation, not in run time

Simple answer: **no**, this is not possible. Not at compile-time. You can check this at runtime though using reflection.

The best you could do with attributes at compile-time (except some special system attributes such as `Obsolete` but which are directly incorporated into the compiler) is specify their usage with the [`[AttributeUsage]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, first of all.
I know, that i can specify usage of attribute (for class, or for properties), but tries to make my library most easy to use as i can. Compiler our friend and our mission - give him as more information as we can. It's more comfortable to get error on compile time, than at run-time.

Comment: @Yavanosta, I agree that it would have been better to provide compile-time safety rather than runtime but in this case you shouldn't be using attributes as they work at runtime with reflection. So you get no safety. Maybe you should rethink your design.